# Magento 2: Is there a way to lock indexer programmatically?

Tags: magento2, import, reindex, table, indexer

When I run my custom import script, and during it's execution starts **`reindex`**, it causes the error :

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when
>   trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was:
>
> `INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_datetime` ... 
>   and other
>   `catalog_product_entity_* tables`

How can I avoid these errors?

I thinking about a few ways:

1. Lock indexer
2. Lock tables (bad idea)
3. Temporary disable cron (even more bad idea)
4. Extend and override core indexer and manually write the code that will check 
   some lock files.

I can't find any information about indexer locking in Magento 2.

**And another question:** It can be a problem with the deadlock not at all in reindex and import?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code which might help you (I took it from \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer::reindexAll):

```
$state = $stateFactory->create();
$state->loadByIndexer({indexer_id});
$state->setStatus(StateInterface::STATUS_WORKING);
$state->save();
```